# Cached Logins proxying

Tags: php, python, proxy, squid

I want the proxy server to store/overwrite all session information across all clients. This should allow all clients to be logged into a websites simultaneously: ie. you log into a website with one browser via the proxy from Client1 and all the session information will be recycled for Client2, which will effectively be logged in. I am well aware of the security implications, but all proxies are designed to avoid this and sharing account passwords is not an option!

I have looked at various proxies like squid3 and a few others, but all of them seem not to be able to do what I want due to the security issues it causes. Even simple php proxy scripts are programmed to avoid this problem. Where would I look to construct something like this on my own?

Many thanks

Comment: How do logins for the used application work? Is it form-based and thus handled by the application itself, or is HTTP-Auth being used? Or something completly different? The possibility of achieving your goal, to my knowledge, heavily depends on this factor. Spoiler: I can only imagine achieving this with HTTP-Auth at the backend.

Comment: If it would be http-auth the solution would be pretty straightforward. I need to discard all session information from the clients and send the cached session info/authentication cookies instead. So say facebook: You log in once from Computer A and then if you visit from Computer B you are already logged in.